# Error al crear link de vistas - Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, xampp, framework

Estoy en clases de desarrollo web y estoy empezando a usar el framework codeigniter. Todo iba bien con las guias y la elaboracion del pequeño proyecto hasta que el profesor en las guias nos indica como crear secciones en el controlador, basicamente para cargar otra serie de vistas(de otra seccion del sitio) sin tener que craer otro controlador, es lo que entiendo, y bueno, me da error.. A continuacion muestro mi proyecto y la guia que estoy estudiando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, tengo el controlador y mis vistas de la funcion index cargando bien. tengo configurado correctamente el autoload y el routes. Asi de la manera en que estan elaboradas las funciones galeria, contacto y registrate es como se me indica que deben ser creadas en el controlador de inicio que carga las vistas de index. En la vista menu es donde tengo enlazadas estas secciones en el nav bar que se ve alli, pero cuando doy click para acceder a estas secciones me da este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede ayudarme a corregir eso le agradeceria un monton. La verdad no entiendo que tengo mal.

Aca dejo algunas capturas de la guia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestras puede deberse más a un problema de reescritura de urls que a un problema del controlador ya que estas utilizando subdirectorios para tus proyectos.

Debes primero comprobar si la configuración de apache contiene el módulo correspondiente, para ello debes ir al panel de control y editar el archivo `httpd.conf`

[image: panel de control xampp]

... y verificar que `mod_rewrite` este activo y que no este comentado (quitar el `#` si lo tiene):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

tambien verificar que dentro de la configuración del directorio contenga la opción `AllowOverride` en `All` si no agregarlo tambien.

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

También debes crear/editar el archivo `.htaccess` que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta de cada uno de tus proyectos, que esta junto al `index.php` para que tenga lo siguiente:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /nombre_del_subdirectorio
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

<sup>*sustituir *nombre_del_subdirectorio* por el nombre de tu carpeta</sup>

Con esto podrás sobrescribir la url de tus proyectos y evitar el error 404.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda el tiempo que te tomaste para responder a mi pregunta. Ayer mismo pude encontrar el error y es que era una total estupides... El archivo .htaccess en la raiz lo habia escrito solo con una s y no con doble s... Que cagada la mia