# ¿Por qué mi aplicación no corre en localhost en CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo esta fracción de código en el archivo `config/config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/app';
```

Pero cuando intento ejecutarla en esa dirección en mi navegador, no funciona. Estoy usando XAMPP en Mac OS aunque también uso Windows y tampoco funciona.

Pero funciona bien si cambio esto:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://midominio.com';
```

¿Por qué es que no me funciona de forma local?

Comment: Básicamente $config['base_url'] no te ayuda a cambiar el directorio de tu proyecto, esta configuración solo te permite generar [urls dinámicas](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html) a partir de tu dominio (midominio.com | localhost)

Comment: Por lo que noto en tu localhost, estas utilizando una instancia dentro de un subdirectorio (/app), aunque desconozco la estructura de tu proyecto o la versión de CodeIgniter que estas utilizando

Comment: Mi version de codeigniter es la 3.x por lo que puedo deducir, no se mucho de este tema, pero por la estructura se me asimiló a esta versión, como puedo hacer para que me funcione localhost? porque si en base_url coloco un dominio si funciona.

Comment: ¿Ambas pruebas las estas realizando en local? o ¿Utilizas un dominio?, talvez se deba más a un problema de reescritura de urls: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/380921/65107

Comment: las 2 pruebas que estoy haciendo una es en local y otra es en dominio (esta si funciona)

Comment: Ya resolví el inconveniente y era una configuración de xampp tal cual está en este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272731/using-mod-rewrite-with-xampp-and-windows-7-64-bit